# How to Test React Native Functions That Call Native Code Libraries Without Mocking

Tags: reactjs, react-native, testing, mocking

My application is written in React Native, and I use the JestJs library to test functions in my project. However, some functions call libraries written in Native Code. JestJs has a limitation that it cannot test these native code libraries, for example, the @react-native-async-storage/async-storage library.

I have a workaround for this issue which is to use the Detox library to write functions that call these native code libraries, then display the output on the UI and use Detox to test the UI. However, this method is time-consuming and quite slow.

So, how can I write tests to test my functions and those libraries? Of course, I want the actual output from the native code libraries instead of mocking.